# Configure sailsjs to redirect unknown routes as /#/path for angularjs when html5 mode is true

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I'm using sailjs with angularjs routing and I need html5 mode to be true, but any hard page load except /index.html generates a 404 error. In the non-sailsjs case when using plain nodejs, you would add something in your routes to re-write anything not matched by existing routes as `/#/route` on index.html. But I do not know how to do this in sailsjs.

In regular node.js, it would be something like:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
   return res.redirect('/#' + req.path);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular and Sails routing configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957465/angular-and-sails-routing-configuration) Besides the solution in the previous link, you can also separate your server from your client (angularjs), when sails serves as an api only.

Comment: Regarding html5 mode == false, you can't do anything with hashes on server side (not only in Sails but anywhere else).